# How do I create the object from a method outside of the main class and print the result from the constructor?

Tags: java

My assignment is: Complete the getAverage() method in the ArrayAverage class using a for-each loop. Create an ArrayAverage object and print the result.

Your output should be:

The average of the array is 36.5

```
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int[] numArray =  {12, 17, 65, 7, 30, 88};
     
     // Create an ArrayAverage object and print the result 
     //ArrayAverage myAverage = new ArrayAverage();
     
    System.out.println("The average of the array is " + getAverage(numArray));
   }
}

public class ArrayAverage
{
   private int[] values;

   public ArrayAverage(int[] theValues)
   {
      values = theValues;
   }

   public double getAverage()
   {
     
     double sum = 0;
     double average = 0.0;
     for(int val : values){
         sum += val;
     }
     
     average = ((double)sum/values.length);
     return average;
     
   }
}
```

This is the assignment I've completed. I've completed the getAverage() method but I need help creating the ArrayAverage object and printing the result. I'm a beginner and my teacher hasn't explained anything so please explain to me kindly what the answer is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `numArray` variable into the `new ArrayAverage(numArray)` constructor like so. And then to use that value, call `myAverage.getAverage()` in the print statement you have.

Also, when you store the average at the end with:
`average = ((double)sum/values.length);`
you don't need the cast to a `double` since `sum` is already a `double`. You can just return the result:
`return sum / values.length;`